# Xamarin form :How to connect bluetooth printer and print reciept

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am recieving json data in my app. I need to know how i can connect mobile from app with bluetooth printer and print json data ?

Comment: Does your printer supports TCP or more specific, Is it an ECS printer?

Comment: its doesnt matter if its tcp or ecs printer i just need to connect with any bluetooth printer